# Cygwin is trimming my android.mk path

Tags: android, path, android-ndk, cygwin, gnu-make

I'm compiling my project Android project with Cygwin like this

**bash.exe -i [ANDROID_NDK_HOME]/ndk-build -j4**

and I'm having this issue on win7 x86

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /cygdrive/d/jni/Android.mk
/cygdrive/d/DevTools/android-ndk/build/core/add-application.mk:118: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

The path of my android.mk should be /cygdrive/d/my_app/android/my_project/jni/Android.mk

**Why cygwin is trimming my path string?**

In other pc this issue doesn't happen (Win 7 x64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "-i" will work. I believe you should use "--login -c". Also you must use cd to correct directory before running ndk-build. When I was using Cygwin for Android NDK I was running following bat file to run ndk-build command in current directory under cygwin:

```
set ANDROID_NDK=C:\android\ndk
set CYGWIN=C:\cygwin

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('%CYGWIN%\bin\cygpath.exe "%cd%"') do set CUR_DIR=%%A
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('%CYGWIN%\bin\cygpath.exe "%ANDROID_NDK%"') do set NDK_DIR=%%A

%CYGWIN%\bin\bash --login -c "cd %CUR_DIR% && %NDK_DIR%/ndk-build -j4"
```

But now I don't use cygwin anymore. Android NDK can run ndk-build.cmd as native bat file from native Windows command line (cmd.exe) without any need for Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solutions. We also resolved the issue by moving the project folder to the root C directory. I will really keep in mind your several solutions, if this happens with this problem again to saver time.